# Voice call with physical phones using Python

Tags: python, voip

I am wondering whether there exists a solution for placing voice calls (calling actual numbers) in Python.

Comment: [I just typed `import phone`](http://xkcd.com/353/).

Comment: "calling actual numbers"?  That's what a modem does, right?  It lives on a serial port, right?  What interface do you have to these "physical phones"?  Please specify how your computer will control the phone.  Is it through a modem?

Comment: Yeah! I saw that XKCD comic b4. Also, try using a virtual phone service to call them like pygooglevoice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [this](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP_Tutorial)? It seems to allow you to make calls using Session Initiation Protocol (SIP). Obviously, you need to have an SIP server running somewhere.